# Simulink - MATLAB- I have a matlab function block in Simulink with an if-statement, only one of the two actions of this if statement is executed, why?

Tags: matlab, if-statement, simulink

I have the following function in a simulink block. It takes as an input the value of xi and of xihat, and assess whether xihat should be updated or not. I also want to output whether there was an update, therefore the variable update takes the  value 1 if xihat is updated and -1 if it is not. When I run the Simulink programme, I get the expected values for xihat (when plotted, the data is similar to xi but with a stairs kind of appearance). However the value of up is -1 for all of the simulation time. This is not coherent with the fact that the value of xihat is updated. I have even included a disp('yes') to show when the if statement is executed. In short, when the condition is positive definite, xihat should be updated and up should be assigned 1 and only the former is executed. How is this possible?

I have tried to run this exact same function with the same data in a matlab script and it then runs perfectly and up is coherent with xihat. I have attached an image of the subsystem in which the block is located.

I also tried to change the variable name, change the order of the statements, output the conditions etc and nothing seems to help.

Simulink subsystem with MAtlab block.:

[image]

Comment: Reading your question it appears that the relevant information is the matlab code inside the block. Care sharing it?

Comment: It would be great to have a minimal reproducible example. As @AnderBiguri mentioned, currently there is at least 1 thing missing for that. -- That being said, I don't see why someone voted this question to be off topic.

Comment: @DennisJaheruddin On of the off-topic reasons is "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. "